# Prepare enum list and find an enum value from List<enum>

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, enums

I decided to write the below code for Access Control List permission check.

My database will return a record like `EmployeeDetFeature`,`Create`,`Edit`

I would like to Parse `Create` and add it to a Feature ACL enum list.

Also i need to find it later.

```
public enum ACL
{

    Create,
    Delete,
    Edit,
    Update,
    Execute
}  


public class Feature
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ACL> ACLItems { get; set; }
}




public static class PermissionHelper
{
    public static bool CheckPermission(Role role, string featureName, ACL acl)
    {
        Feature feature = role.Features.Find(f =>f.Name == featureName);
        if (feature != null)
        {
            //Find the acl from enum and if exists return true
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

How do i make it with Enum collection preparation and find the same later for checking permission.

Answer (score 3):

> Find the acl from enum and if exists return true

Something like this?

```
bool b= Enum.GetValues(typeof(ACL)).Cast<ACL>().Any(e => e == acl);
```

Comment: +1 Looks nice. Let me try it. Also i need to see how i am going to assign each string like `Create`, `Edit` to my ACLItems in Feature :(

Comment: +1: sweet. Wish you can add code demonstrating how to access this via extension method, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on .NET 4.0, you can decorate ACL enum with [Flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) attribute and change your model a bit:

```
// Added Flags attribute.
[Flags]
public enum ACL
{
    None = 0,
    Create = 1,
    Delete = 2,
    Edit = 4,
    Update = 8,
    Execute = 16
}

public class Feature
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // ACLItems is not List anymore.
    public ACL ACLItems { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can use [Enum.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx), like in the following example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ACL aclItems = ACL.Create | ACL.Edit | ACL.Execute;

    var aclItemsString = aclItems.ToString();
    // aclItemsString value is "Create, Edit, Execute"

    ACL aclItemsOut;
    if (Enum.TryParse(aclItemsString, out aclItemsOut))
    {
        var areEqual = aclItems == aclItemsOut;
    }
}
```

Comment: Flags are also enabled in previous versions of the .net framework

Comment: Yes, but Enum.TryParse method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx) isn't.